# How to derive 2 dataframes from a dataframe based on the time of the day?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyverse, tibble

I have a `df` (please see below for reproducible data):

```
library(tidyverse)
df
```

```
# A tibble: 6 × 2
     id date               
  <int> <dttm>             
1     1 2015-03-14 17:18:31
2     2 2015-03-14 17:18:56
3     3 2015-03-26 17:18:32
4     4 2015-03-26 17:18:56
5     5 2015-04-07 17:18:32
6     6 2015-04-07 17:18:57
```

Now, using this `df` I want to create 2 new `dataframes` or `tibbles` - `df1` and `df2`.

What I want to achieve is to write a tidy code, that checks if there are 2 rows for the same day (year, month and day are the same) and if there is, the earlier row (checking the time of the day) goes to the first df `df1` and the later row goes to the second df, `df2`.

The desired output for `df1`:

```
# A tibble: 3 × 2
     id date               
  <int> <dttm>             
1     1 2015-03-14 17:18:31
2     3 2015-03-26 17:18:32
3     5 2015-04-07 17:18:32
```

The desired output for `df2`:

```
# A tibble: 3 × 2
     id date               
  <int> <dttm>             
1     2 2015-03-14 17:18:56
2     4 2015-03-26 17:18:56
3     6 2015-04-07 17:18:57
```

P.S: I am specifically interested in knowing the `tidyverse` approach to this problem, but I am also very curious how it would be done using base `R`.

**Reproducible data:**

```
structure(list(id = 1:6, date = structure(c(1426353511, 1426353536, 
1427390312, 1427390336, 1428427112, 1428427137), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"))), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))
```

Comment: In your reproducible data the odd numbers are earlier (or smaller) than the evens. Is this in your real data too?

Comment: @mmw the real data is huge and it is hard to tell the orders for the whole data. Why?

Comment: If you would have every date exactly twice and times would be earlier for odds (or evens) in every case you could just select even and odd rows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
library(data.table) #for the convenience of the as.IDate-function
# split by duplicate-status
L <- split(df, duplicated(as.IDate(df$date)))
# set names
names(L) <- c("df1", "df2")
# pust list's element to current environment (use names of list as objects' names)
list2env(L, envir = environment())
```

Comment: What does this code do if there is only a single row for a day? :)

Comment: then is is not a duplicate, so it should go into `df1`